# How can I do i18n for javascript with Middleman?

Tags: javascript, middleman

Is there something already in the technology stack used by MM that will handle i18n for JS? E.g. something that will take a javascript: section out of an `en.yml` and `es.yml` file and make it available as a `translation.js` file - or something similar (*I only know how its sometimes done in rails*).

Fwiw, https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js seems to be a popular rails solution. I'm guessing the JS parts of that will work just fine. I'm just not sure how to integrate the build process into the MM stack so that all the files get generated and end up the right place.

> @tdreyno suggests: Not currently, but it looks like we could hook up
>   Sprockets (JS) and I18n.

Has anyone done this or have suggestions on how to proceed (for someone who is getting by in Ruby/Rails but hasn't dug around in the 3.1 asset path yet but isn't afraid to try).

Answer (score 1):

I'm just thinking about resolving the exact same problem. So here's my solution:

In `source/layouts/layout.html.slim`:

```
javascript:
  var I18n = {};
  I18n.locale = 'fr';
  I18n.translations = {};
  I18n.translations['fr'] = #{I18n.backend.send(:translations)[:fr].to_json};
```

Then accessing translations in JS is as easy as:

```
I18n.translations.fr['menu']['glossaire']
#=> "Glossaire"
```

Answer (score 0):

caedes' solution is straightforward and workable, but in my case I want to be able to use some of `i18n-js`'s more complex features like string interpolation, rather than just having a set of nested dictionaries.

Luckily, `i18n-js` can [read in from a dictionary](https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js#using-i18njs-with-other-languages-python-php-). I installed `i18n-js` with browserify, imported it globally with `window.I18n = require('i18n-js');` and added a partial `_i18n_js.slim`:

```
javascript:
  I18n.translations = #{I18n.backend.send(:translations).to_json};
```

and then you can use all the features of the excellent [`i18n-js`](https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js).